# What encoding is used in SMS of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms

What encoding is used in SMS of iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7-bit if you only use the characters from the “plain” [GSM character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) in the whole message, 16-bit UTF-16 if you use any characters outside this set.

Comment: So in which character set is "space"?

Comment: So is it UTF-16 bit (binary) or (hex) or (decimal)?

Answer (score 1):

FYI - mixed success when using GSM Extended Char Set (GSM 03.38) where subset of special chars use 2 x 7 bit chars but basic chars are 1 x 7 bit per char (see [long-sms-text-messages-and-the-160-character-limit](https://www.nowsms.com/long-sms-text-messages-and-the-160-character-limit) for good explanation).

Messages with square brackets [ ] (GSM 03.38) routed via one carrier are correctly decoded on iPhone, but the square bracket + following letter are scrambled when received via another carrier (to the same iPhone). Appears to be carrier dependent and not specifically related to iPhone because problem also seen on Android.

So beware is using Extended Char Set.